# SiriKit Payment to an organization?

Tags: ios, sirikit

Someone asked this same question and it got closed for being too vague, but I have this exact problem and it hasn't been answered anywhere else. SiriKit Payment doc says it works User-to-User, but is there any way to make this pay a bill for services? In other words, can the receiving "user" be a bank or somehow be re-routed to a bank or a server for payment processing?

Comment: I can't see any reason that *technically*  the recipient can't be an organisation; you can register a custom contact into the vocabulary and it is up to your  app as to how it processes the payment. I think the difficulty of your question is whether Apple would *allow* such functionality, and that is off-topic

Comment: My question is if it can be done. If Apple doesn't allow it then it can't. Not sure how that's off-topic. That's exactly the topic.

Comment: Because "what Apple allows" is primarily opinion-based unless you are Apple, so it is off-topic

Comment: Oh you're saying it would get rejected in the submission process. Gotcha. Thought you meant they wouldn't allow the API to function that way.

Comment: Exactly. All the payment intent does is pass some data to your app saying that user wants to pay $x to person y when the user tells Siri something like "pay $50 to MyTelephoneCompany with CoolBillPayer". Using SiriKit your app can add "MyTelephoneCompany" to the Siri vocabulary as a contact and register itself as supporting the payment intent for "CoolBillPayer". It is then up to your app to process the payment in some way.  The API doesn't know what your app does once the intent fires

Comment: All the examples I've seen say "to Paul" or "to x person's name" as recipients so it seemed like it had to be another user who was also running iOS (and possibly also had the app). I've yet to see one that said "to MyPhoneCompany." That's what I was unsure about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127666/discussion-between-paulw11-and-bill-k).